# Does the title of Bobobo-bo bobo-bo mean anything?

Tags: japanese-language, bobobo-bo-bo-bobo

Bobobo-bo Bobo-bo (ボボボーボ・ボーボボ) is certainly a strange anime, but does the title mean anything?

The main character's name is also Bobobo-bo Bobo-bo (Bo-Bobo for short - but not Bo).

Some of the other names in the series are jokes - there is someone called Beauty and another called Don Patch (a pun on "donpachi", the Japanese sound of machine gun fire).

Is there some joke in his name (apart from the obvious absurdity)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bōbō (ぼうぼう or ボーボー) is a common [phenomime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_sound_symbolism) (non-auditory onomatopoeia) expressing excessive growth of things such as weed or hair, growing all over the place and unkept. The originally planned title was Hanagēbo Bōbobo (ハナゲーボ・ボーボボ), with hanage being nose hair as you may well know. This was scrapped because although Bo-bobo uses his nose hair extensively, his is not exactly growing "all over the place". But the author wanted to keep the phonomime in the title, and ended up with the final title.

Comment: Could you link to external citations/references to support your answer?